# exclusive touch function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my app i have an `UISlider` which is subview of `UIScrollView`, where everything is done programatically.  Here i have set,

```
 scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
```

When i set this **UISlider** also disabled, i.e i can't able to access UISlider, here i need to set `userInteractionEnabled` to **NO** only for my `scrollview`, for this issue i have used,

```
scrollview.exclusivetouch=NO;
```

but still i can't able to access UISlider. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if touch event is detected by UISlider, tell your UIScrollview to pass an event to UISlider.

Make sure you have implemented this properties.

```
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

And one more thing, don't depend on result of simulator.

check in real device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

That way, touches are handled, but scrolling is disabled (unless you set the `contentOffset` programatically).

Comment: userInteractionEnabled set to NO on a parent view is cascade down to all subviews. i want this property to set only on parentview.